# Looping over an ARRAY of TIMESTAMPS in psql for complex SELECT

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, loops

I'm trying to grab a ton of features on a few tables and I'm at my current pSQL capacity. Using 9.6.2.

I'm trying to gather all these features at a variable amount of datetimes. Currently, I'm running this on a single timestamp, and have to call it over and over, which is too slow for my use.

I'd like to send this an array of timestamps that are used in the FROM(...UNION...).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION features_at_times(timestamp[])
  RETURNS TABLE (
        str_street_id                      varchar,
        ....blahhh, blah, blah.......
        Zone                               integer,
        DateTime                           timestamp
    ) AS
$func$
DECLARE
  stamp timestamp[];
  stamps timestamp[]:= array[];
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    FOREACH stamp SLICE 1 IN ARRAY $1
    LOOP
        SELECT
          str_stuff_id,
          .....blahhh, blah, blah....
          COALESCE(MAX(zone_id), 0) "Zone",
          MAX("DateTime") "DateTime"

        FROM (

          SELECT
            thingo.*,
            str_timezone,
            timestamp stamp AT TIME ZONE str_timezone "DateTime"
          FROM thingo
          JOIN destination ON pk_city = pk_destination
          WHERE pk_city = '8fzdd56-7a52-11df-a34f-6b84rw853d3d'
          AND thingo.pk_thingo_status = 2

          UNION

          SELECT
              alt_thingo.*,
              str_timezone,
              timestamp stamp AT TIME ZONE str_timezone "DateTime"
          FROM thingo
          JOIN thingo AS alt_thingo USING (str_stuff_id)
          JOIN destination ON thingo.pk_city = pk_destination
          WHERE thingo.pk_city = '8fzdd56-7a52-11df-a34f-6b84rw853d3d'
          AND thingo.pk_thingo_status = 2

      ) as base
      LEFT JOIN block_observation_by_bin
          ON thingo_observation_by_bin.thingo_id = pk_thingo_id
          AND thingo_observation_by_bin.bin_id = ((to_char("DateTime",'D')::int - 1) * 24 + to_char("DateTime", 'HH24')::int)
          AND thingo_observation_by_bin.market_id = 94
      LEFT JOIN block_observation
          ON thingo_observation.thingo_id = pk_thingo_id
          AND thingo_observation.market_id = 94

      WHERE base.pk_thingo = '027ecb54-51ec-41a6-a57e-666fddbbff35'
      GROUP BY str_stuff_id;

    END LOOP;
  END;
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I need this same reading at n number of times. I see FOREACH is an option, but I've been getting nothing but errors. I'd like to pass in timestamps to the inner two SELECTS.

Also, do I have to use a function to use a FOREACH in psql?

Comment: You can use unnest instead, like this `CROSS JOIN (SELECT unnest($1) AS stamp) AS stamps`. Then you don't need plpgsql; it will be just one query to execute, so `language sql` will be enough.

Answer (score 1):

The argument of `RETURN QUERY` has to be an SQL statement, but `FOREACH` is PL/pgSQL and not SQL.

Also,

```
timestamp stamp AT TIME ZONE str_timezone "DateTime"
```

is not valid SQL. I didn't check for further errors.

To return rows from several tables in one PL/pgSQL function, you will have to loop with cursors like this:

```
DECLARE
   ats timestamp without time zone;
   arow record;
BEGIN
   /* loop through the timestamps in the argument array */
   FOREACH ats IN ARRAY $1 LOOP
      /* loop through the results of the first query */
      FOR arow IN
         SELECT ...
      LOOP
         RETURN NEXT ...;
      END LOOP;
      /* loop through the results of the second query */
      FOR arow IN
         SELECT ...
      LOOP
         RETURN NEXT ...;
      END LOOP;
      ...
   END LOOP;
END;
```